# Program to find the consecutive alphabets and print it

Tags: java

public class NoOfConsAlphabet {

```
/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    String str="aaabbddaabbcc";
    int count=1;
    String finalString="";
    for(int i=1;i<str.length()-1;i++)
        {
            if(str.charAt(i)==str.charAt(i+1))
            {
                ++count;

            }
            else
            {

                finalString+=str.charAt(i)+count+",";
                count=1;
            }   

        }
    System.out.println(finalString);
    }
```

}

I am getting this as my o/p:99,100,102,99,100,
Can someone tell me how to get this resolved not sure what this is?

however the below program using split works
public class NoOfConsAlphabet {

```
/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    String str="aaabbddaabbcc";
    String[] splitString=str.split("");
    int count=1;
    String finalString="";
    for(int i=1;i<str.length()-1;i++)
        {
            if(splitString[i].equals(splitString[i+1]))
            {
                ++count;

            }
            else
            {

                finalString+=splitString[i]+count+",";
                count=1;
            }   

        }
    System.out.println(finalString);
    }
```

}
o/p:a3,b2,d2,a2,b2,

Comment: What do you mean consecutive alphabets? Based on the expected output, it looks like all you need to do is check if `charAt(i) == charAt(i + 1)`?

Comment: What happens when you run it in a debugger?

Comment: On concatenating to the finalString i get the ascii code of the characters w/o the count:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The algorithm user3296744 seems to be working on is [Run-length encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-length_encoding).

The problem here is not just that the actual output:

```
"o/p:a1b3d2a2b2c2"
```

does not match the desired output:

```
"o/p:3a, 2b, 2d, 2a, 2b, 2c"
```

but on closer inspection, that the count from the actual output is shifted by one with respect to the accompanying letter; that is, where the 3 should be matched with the `a`, it is matched with the `b`, and so on.

If you run your code in debug mode with a break point after the line:

```
String[] str2=str.split("");
```

You will notice that the `str2` array is not quite what you would expect. Rather than being an array with 13 elements, it actually has 14 elements with the first element being a `null`.

As such I would suggest that you avoid using the `split()` function, and instead of breaking the string into an array you could use the `charAt()` function to access the desired characters. Note: this may require you modify your for loop to the standard version rather than the for each version.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure this could be done shorter and sweeter but...

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {  
        findAndPrintConsecutiveCharacters("aaabbddaabbcc");
    }

    private static void findAndPrintConsecutiveCharacters(String sToPrint){

        for(int i = 0; i < sToPrint.length(); i ++){
            char c = sToPrint.charAt(i);
            int occurences = 1;

            if(i <= sToPrint.length() - 2) { //limit the nested for so we dont go out of bounds

            for (int i2 = i + 1; i2 < sToPrint.length(); i2 ++){
                char c2 = sToPrint.charAt(i2);

                if(c2 == c)
                    occurences += 1;
                else{
                    i += occurences - 1; //shift i by the amount of occurences, this will prevent counting consecutive chars multiple times
                    break;
                }
            }

            }
            else
                break; //we are on our last char

            System.out.println(String.valueOf(occurences) + String.valueOf(c));
        }

    }

}
```

outputs

```
3a
2b
2d
2a
2b
2c
```

I would suggest you use better naming conventions and already-defined constructs like String.charAt() instead of splitting by an empty regex. What you have might work if you hack around with it but it is extremely confusing to read if you are reassigning that "pointer" as you've named it.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Test1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    
    String word = "aaabbbcddeeeuu";
    int count = 1 ;
    String finalString="";
    
    for(int i=0;i<word.length();i++)
    
    {
        if( i+1 <word.length() && word.charAt(i)==word.charAt(i+1))
        {
            
            
            count++;
            
        
        }
        
        else 
        {
            finalString += word.charAt(i)+""+count;
            count=1;
            
        }
        
        
        
        
    }
    System.out.println(finalString);
    
    }

}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).